# Trapezoidal screw usage on robot arm rods

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics, stepper-motor

I'd like to build toy on picture - uStepper/EEzy robot arm. I'm little bit afraid of plastic gears - backslash, weakness, noise... Do you think trapezoidal screw will perform better when I use them on arm rods? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you wondering about plastic vs steel or between the various types of threads (all in plastic)?

Comment: Plastic gears are more quiet than metal and wear less (against other plastic gears) which improves on back lash and noise. Worm drives are NOISY and inefficient (lots of friction) but passively maintain position under load which could be important.

Comment: Original arm has plastic gears connected to rods (red arrows on the picture) and I'm thinking about cheap metal trapezoidal screw (at right on the picture), known from 3d printers